# android php json cant deserialized json into type error- how to resloved

Tags: php, xamarin

I am creating php query to fetch data from mysql database. and create class in xamarin based on this data. but when run the app I get error (cant deserialized json type ...). what is wrong in my json or class. note that the database table contain three column (user_id, meta_key, meta_value).

the php query

```
  $sql=mysqli_query($con,"select * FROM mohamiusermeta  where meta_key='websiteurl' or meta_key='profile_photo' or meta_key = 'Office' or meta_key='address_user' or meta_key='agentarea' or meta_key='offertext' or meta_key='officename' or meta_key='cover_photo' or meta_key='membertype'");
  $newarray = array();

  while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
  {
    if (!array_key_exists($row['user_id'], $newarray)) {
    $newarray[$row['user_id']] = ['user_id' => $row['user_id']];
  }
  $newarray[$row['user_id']][$row['meta_key']] = $row['meta_value'];
}

json_encode($newarray);

echo(json_encode($newarray,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE));

mysqli_close();
```

my class in xamarin android

```
      [JsonProperty("user_id")]
    public string UserID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Office")]
    public string Officetag { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("officename")]
    public string Officename { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("address_user")]
    public string AddressUser { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("profile_photo")]
    public string ProfilePhoto { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("cover_photo")]
    public string CoverPhoto { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("agentarea")]
    public string Agentarea { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("offertext")]
    public string Offertext { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("websiteurl")]
    public string Websiteurl { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("membertype")]
    public string Membertype { get; set; }
```

to check json in browser 
http://lifecareclub.net/api/test.php

thank you in advance

my error

Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the  current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Lifecare.Galeri]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
Path '107', line 1, position 7.

my code line error

```
            itemGaleri = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Galeri>>  (e.Result);
```

Comment: Can you please provide us the source code where the trailing bracket is belonging to and also maybe the starting line numbers and the full error message?

Comment: Are you sure that your code can parse object in first level of json?

Comment: I updated my question